# sql - query instead of group by

Tags: sql, oracle

in my school we learn with oracle sql developer.
my task is simple.
I need to count how many identical values in the same column, for example:

```
  COLA    COLB    COLC    ....
  A       ...     ...     ....
  A       ...     ...     ....
  A       ...     ...     ....
  B       ...     ...     ....
  B       ...     ...     ....
  C       ...     ...     ....
  C       ...     ...     ....
  D       ...     ...     ....
```

so i need the info of: how many A's, how many B's and on.

The important thing is that i can not use group by.
The only things I can use is:

`select`, `from`, `where`, `union`, `intersect`,  `minus`, `distinct`, `count`, `and`, `or`, `as`, `between`.

can not figure that out by now, any help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  Can you complete the sample table above and also show us your expected output?

Comment: the rest of the table is irelevant, all i need is the info of how many equals vales i have in the same column.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, your question is how to achieve the GROUP BY without using GROUP BY.

```
SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE COLA = t.COLA) FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT COLA FROM tbl
) AS t
```

Comment: Nice idea. But: `AS t` will result in an error in Oracle - the `AS` keyword is not supported for table aliases

Comment: the table that i gave is only as example, my table is build from ids. so its an unknown set of variables. i can not use join and sub query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `UNION`.  It assumes that you only have letters `A` through `D` though.

```
SELECT COUNT(COLA) AS theCount, 'A' as theType
From table
WHERE COLA = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(COLA) AS theCount, 'B' as theType
From table
WHERE COLA = 'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(COLA) AS theCount, 'C' as theType
From table
WHERE COLA = 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(COLA) AS theCount, 'D' as theType
From table
WHERE COLA = 'D'
```

This will give you an output table looking something like this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╗
║ theCount ║ theType ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║     3    ║    A    ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║     2    ║    B    ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║     2    ║    C    ║
╠══════════╬═════════╣
║     1    ║    D    ║
╚══════════╩═════════╝
```

**Disclaimer:** This solution is nice if you only have a few types of column values.  If you have either an unknown set of values or a large number of known values, this is not the way to go.

Comment: You should move ` 'A' as theType` in the select clause.

Comment: Unions won't suppress any lines because A is different from B, C, etc. So why you don't put `union all`? It is misleading...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for finding duplicates count

```
SELECT 
  colA, count(colA)
FROM myTable a
JOIN myTable b
ON  a.colA = b.colA 
AND a.ROWID > b.ROWID
```

Comment: I like this answer, but he doesn't seem to list `JOIN` as a permissible keyword.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the explicit `JOIN` can be replaced with the old-fashioned implicit join condition in the `where` clause

Answer (score 1):

So, you just need to count values without using the `group by` clause...

```
select distinct cola, cnt
from(  
     select cola, count(*) over (partition by cola) as cnt
     from table
     )
```

That *count over partition by* thing is [analytic function syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55)